# How to classify tests according to test sizes in JUnit

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4, junit5

Given I have test sizes: *small*, *medium* and *large* as described in https://testing.googleblog.com/2010/12/test-sizes.html.

How can I classify all my tests according to test sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@org.junit.experimental.categories.Category` with JUnit 4 or `@org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag` with JUnit Jupiter (a.k.a., the programming model for JUnit 5).